# Best Linear Predictors for two-way nested classification model

Tags: anova, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

#### 1. Summarize the problem

How can I make predictions for the random effects in a two-way nested ANOVA with unbalanced data?

Given the model for the two-way classification

$y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_j + \beta_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ijk}$

$E(y_{ijk}) = \mu$

$\alpha_j \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_a^2)$

$\beta_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_b^2)$

$\varepsilon_{ijk} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_e^2)$

I am aware that there are solutions to this problem in R using `lme4` for instance. But I am interested in the formulation of the predictors:

$\hat\alpha_j = \; ?$

$\hat\beta_{ij} = \; ?$

I know that the predictors depend on the estimators of the variances $\hat\sigma_a^2, \hat\sigma_b^2, \hat\sigma_e^2$.

#### 2. Provide details and any research

My main resource is [Variance Components by Searle, Casella and McCulloch](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316856). They derive a BLP for the one-way classification. I am not in a position to extrapolate these results to the two-way classification. I'm open for further references.